# c# emgu.cv trying to copy mat.Data returnl null

Tags: c#, tensorflow, machine-learning, emgucv, mat

I have written such code for object detection in Emgu.cv C#:

```
Image<Bgr, byte> image1 = new Image<Bgr, byte>("testing.png");
        int interception = 0;

        Net netcfg = DnnInvoke.ReadNetFromTensorflow(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"pbs\t1.pb", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"pbs\graph.pbtxt");

        netcfg.SetInput(DnnInvoke.BlobFromImage(image1.Mat, 1, new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300), default(MCvScalar), true, false));

        Mat mat = netcfg.Forward();
        var arr = mat.Data;
```

However, when I'm debugging my code in Visual Studio 2019, I see, that mat.Data is System.Array float[,,,], but when I'm assigning this value to a variable, it is always null. So, in this code i can see a huge float[,,,] array in mat.Data in debugging mode, but after that, variable arr is always null.... Please, help me with that, how could I copy that array from mat.Data to another variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, that was really stupid question...
to get a float[,,,] array from mat.Data, I should'n use it like this:

```
var arr = mat.Data;
```

the right way is to use:

```
var arr = mat.GetData();
```